# How to replace pointers in python recursively

Tags: python

I am implementing a custom function to clone an object.  Copy.copy is too shallow, and copy.deepcopy is too deep.

For this, I need to replace any occurence of several "pointers" to other objects (I expect that's the wrong terminology for python and I appologise for it) in an object's members and the members of those members (and on down).

My naive approach would be to use dir() to recursively search for values and update them, with a list of already searched objects so as not to get stuck in a loop.  But I'm wondering if there's a better way?

**ADDITION**

My first try is this:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def replace_pointers(object, replace_list):
    if isinstance(object, Iterable):
        for i in range(len(object)):
            if object[i] in replace_list[0]:
                index = replace_list[0].index(object[i])
                object[i] = replace_list[1][index]
    elif hasattr(object, "__dict__"):
        for attr in object.__dict__:
            attr_value = getattr(object, attr)
            if attr_value in replace_list[0]:
                index = replace_list[0].index(attr_value)
                setattr(object, attr, replace_list[1][index])
    else:
        assert 0, f"unrecognised type for replace_pointers: {object}"

#

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import copy

    x = ["I'm x"]
    y = ["I'm y"]

    replace_list = [[x],[y]]

    z1 = [x,x,x]

    z1_copy = copy.copy(z1)
    replace_pointers(z1_copy, replace_list)

    print(z1)
    print(z1_copy)

    class A():
        def __init__(self):
            pass

    z2 = A
    z2.foo = x
    z2.boo = x

    z2_copy = copy.copy(z2)
    replace_pointers(z2_copy, replace_list)

    print(z2.__dict__)
    print(z2_copy.__dict__)
```

This gives the output:

```
[["I'm x"], ["I'm x"], ["I'm x"]]
[["I'm y"], ["I'm y"], ["I'm y"]]
{'__module__': '__main__', '__init__': <function A.__init__ at 0x7f190c3167a0>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None, 'foo': ["I'm y"], 'boo': ["I'm y"]}
{'__module__': '__main__', '__init__': <function A.__init__ at 0x7f190c3167a0>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None, 'foo': ["I'm y"], 'boo': ["I'm y"]}
```

So it works for the list, but it doesn't for the object (it changes the original as well as the new one, which I'm blanking on for the reason of)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far along with example input and desired output?

Comment: To 'replace a point to another object' you just assign that new object as the value of whatever our old object is...  z= [x];  z[0]=y. Replaces the reference to x with a reference to y, assuming x and y are mutable objects.